# Htaccess redirect rule for query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a list of 200 broken URLs and their corresponding working URLs. The broken URLs have query strings. Some of the parameter values have a `/` in it.

Example:

```
mysite.com/dir1/dir2/page?param1=value1&param2=value2/value3
```

I've tried this as a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/dir1/dir2/page1?param1=value1&param2=value2/value3 http://www.mysite.com/page2 [R=301,L]
```

I don't need to pattern match using regular expressions because I have a list of broken and working URLs or do I need a RewriteCond for each one?

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use this site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update this should work just fine:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=ranges/bella/colours/satin/ivory&colour=ivory/bedroom$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /bella/colours/satin/ivory/bedroom? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ranges/visions/colours$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^range=visions&grid_type=colours/bedroom$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /visions/colours/bedroom? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Another example is: mysite.com/?param1=value1/value2/value3/&param2=value4&param3=value5. So I need to match the whole url including the query string. But I don't need to do a search and replace (e.g. replace value1 with value 2).

Comment: From: www.mysite.com?q=ranges/bella/colours/satin/ivory&range=bella&grid_type=styles&colour_group=satin&colour=ivory/bedroom. To: www.mysite.com/bella/colours/satin/ivory/bedroom.

Comment: From: www.mysite.com/ranges/visions/colours?range=visions&grid_type=colours/bedroom. To: www.mysite.com/visions/colours/bedroom.

Comment: I need to match the exact url: folder and page plus the query string and redirect each one to a specific url.

Comment: Perfect! Now I just need to write all the rules... Thanks for your help. David